# Is there a way to make eclipse detect your custom view as its parent layout?

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, android-relativelayout

I've created a custom view extending RelativeLayout, and added its complete name in an xml layout file,, Its working fine I am just asking is there a way to make eclipse detect my parent layout as a RelativeLayout in order to auto-complete and suggest the tags related to RelativeLayout not give me blank suggestion and saying eclipse does't know any direct childs for this component.

```
<com.mypackage.myview> 
<!-- I want eclipse to detect that myView which is in com.mypackage extends RelativeLayout and show the suggestions such as Layout_align_parent_left-->
<Button ............... />
<TextView..................../>
</com.mypackage.myview>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in an older ADT, and its now fixed.

[Reference](http://tools.android.com/recent/adt12bugfixroundup)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is going to work, but try

```
<RelativeLayout class="com.mypackage.myview" ...> 
    <Button .../>
    <TextView .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```